# Can't return Array from database

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in my Snowflake database. I want to get data from columns.

Example of data:

```
id          tid           categories
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
v-123       t-123         ["tx-b5mmqcpooa0p","tx-b5mmqcpood0p"]
b-123       t-124         ["tx-b5mmfcpooa0p","tx-b4mmqcpood0p"]
x-123       t-125         []
b-123       t-124         ["tx-b5mmfcpooa0p","tx-b4mmqcpood0p","tx-bmqcpood0p"]
```

I tried to use pandas:

```
sql = SELECT id, tid, categories FROM table 
df = pandas.read.sql(con, sql)
```

I got this as results:

```
id          tid           categories
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
"v-123"       "t-123"         " ["tx-b5mmqcpooa0p","tx-b5mmqcpood0p"] "
"b-123"       "t-124"         " ["tx-b5mmfcpooa0p","tx-b4mmqcpood0p"] "
"x-123"       "t-125"         " [] "
"b-123"       "t-124"         " ["tx-b5mmfcpooa0p","tx-b4mmqcpood0p","tx-bmqcpood0p"] "
```

The type of ‘categories’ is string instead of array (list).

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snowflake documentation https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#variant-array-and-object-support recommends using `json.loads` to convert to array.

Comment: Yes, you are right ```df['categories'] = df['categories'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x) if x else [])```